# Collect number through prompt

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, type-conversion

I'm trying to collect a number from the user so I can set the width of an image. Heres my code:

```js
function setDefaultWidth() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();

  var result = ui.prompt(
      'New Width (must be a number):',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    defaultImageWidth = Int32Array(text) //tried this but i get TypeError: Constructor Int32Array requires 'new'
  }
}
```

How can I do this? I've tried using Int32Array, but it is not working.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: unclear how Int32Array referes to an image.... but the error message tells you to use `new`

Comment: Just use parseInt().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MetaMan:

> Just us parseInt()

Thanks, it works! (added this as a answer so more people can find it)